# Getting Axis 2 error while trying to use BIRT to web service as a data source

Tags: java, web-services, namespaces, wsdl, birt

I have created a web service which returns an object, one of the fields of which is a json String. I am able to use SOAP UI to test the service and it works fine. However, when I try to use BIRT to the same web service as the data source, it is not able to fetch any records and the following error is printed to the console: **org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: namespace mismatch require http://webservices.xyz.com found http://valueobjects.xyz.com/xsd**

The service was deployed using Tomcat 7 on Eclipse with Axis 2. I have used a different web service for BIRT so, I have basic idea about this. However, I am not sure whether this issue is because of error in XPath or the namespace in wsdl/Java Code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the issue.

- add `<schema elementFormDefaultQualified="false"/>` in the root  tag of services.xml file located in the WEB-INF/Services/service-name/META-INF
- replace the SOAP request template with the one create by the SOAP UI. Be sure to put the parameter in this form: &?parameter?&